# How do I make an ASP.Net validator dependent on another validator

Tags: asp.net, validation

In my ASP.Net application, I have a text box that is decorated as a Datepicker with the jQueryUI. I have two ASP.Net compare validators on the text box. One is a compare validator that does a DataType check. The second is a compare validator that makes sure the entered date is greater than a specified date.

My problem is that if the user hand enters a date of 2/31/11, two error messages are displayed, one for the valid date comparison and one for the greater than comparison. Because the entered date is not a valid date, I want that error message to be displayed. However, I don't want the second error message to be displayed.

My problem is that when a user enters an invalid date the second compare validator is correctly determining that the data is invalid, but I don't want it to display anything because the first validator has it covered. Is there a way to only use the second comparison validator is the first compare validator passes? Can I make the second compare validator dependent on the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is related and might help you: [Extending ASP.NET validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381076/extending-asp-net-validators)

But i would suggest to simply use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that validates both conditions like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149640/how-to-do-a-validator-for-two-controls-dependent-on-each-other/4149674#4149674).

Or use a [ValidatorCalloutExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ValidatorCallout/ValidatorCallout.aspx). That control makes only the first ValidatorCalloutExtender visible.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtDate" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="VG_SAVE"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CompareValidator ID="DateFormat" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TxtDate" Display="None" EnableClientScript="true" ErrorMessage="Enter valid Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" style="visibility:hidden" Type="Date" ValidationGroup="VG_SAVE">*</asp:CompareValidator> 
<asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="DateFormatExtender" runat="server" CloseImageUrl="~/images/close.gif" HighlightCssClass="highlight" TargetControlID="DateFormat"  WarningIconImageUrl="~/images/warning.gif" Width="150px" />
```